# Using Ada to Read and write to a file (parse data for processing)

Tags: file, ada

For those who know about Ada programming, what is a good way to bring data from a file into this program so it can be used in this algorithm?

Using Ada I am trying figure out how to read a series of matrix connection data grids from a file then parse the data, keeping the field names for later output while using the 0's and 1's in the algorithm.

Ideally, the input data will look like this (the number of row and columns will vary and there will be more than one set (matrix) of data with different row and column names in the input file.

example:(ignore underscores)

________Name1_Name2_Name3_NameN

Name1_____0_____1_____0_____0

Name2_____0_____0_____1_____1

Name3_____0_____0_____1_____0

NameN_____0_____1_____0_____0

Here is the code I have so far without the read from file and output to file implementation.

```
WITH Text_IO; USE Text_IO;      -- This gets the IO facility. 
WITH Ada.Integer_Text_IO; USE Ada.Integer_Text_IO; -- This gets the integer IO facility. 
--**** 
-- use zero elements in array to store size 0,0 and row/column names? 


-- read size 
-- use size to read names of columns 
-- store in array 


-- use size to read first row of data? 
-- as data is read convert from 0/1 to true false and store? 

-- if value read = 0 => array2d(n,n) = false 
-- if value read = 1 => array2d(n,n) = true 


-- * main procedure * 
PROCEDURE BooleanTest IS              -- Main, but no special name is needed.BEGIN 

   N : Integer := 4; -- max size ** to be read 
   OutputConvertion : Integer; 
   Array2d: ARRAY (1..N, 1..N) OF boolean; 

-- * main procedure starts begins* 
BEGIN 
   -- read array size and column names 

   -- hard coded to be read from file 

   Array2d(1, 1) := false; 
   Array2d(1, 2) := false; 
   Array2d(1, 3) := false; 
   Array2d(1, 4) := false; 

   Array2d(2, 1) := false; 
   Array2d(2, 2) := true; 
   Array2d(2, 3) := false; 
   Array2d(2, 4) := true; 

   Array2d(3, 1) := false; 
   Array2d(3, 2) := true; 
   Array2d(3, 3) := false; 
   Array2d(3, 4) := true; 

   Array2d(4, 1) := true; 
   Array2d(4, 2) := false; 
   Array2d(4, 3) := true; 
   Array2d(4, 4) := false; 

   FOR I IN 1..N LOOP 
      FOR J IN 1..N LOOP 
         IF Array2d(J,I) = true THEN --true nodes connected 
            FOR K IN 1..N LOOP 
               Array2d(J,K) := Array2d(J,K) OR Array2d(I,K); 
            END LOOP; 
         END IF; 
      END LOOP; 
   END LOOP; 

-- *********** output to screen ************ 

   FOR I IN 1..N LOOP 
      FOR J IN 1..N LOOP 
         IF Array2d(I,J) = True THEN 
            OutputConvertion := 1; 
         ELSE 
            OutputConvertion := 0; 
         END IF; 
         Put( OutputConvertion); 
         Put(" ");                 
      END LOOP; 
      New_Line(1); 
   END LOOP; 


END BooleanTest; 
-- * main procedure ends *
```

Comment: This question distills down too, (for those who know about Ada programming) what is a good way to bring data from a file into this program so it can be used in this algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your question is, but I sense some confusion about not only I/O but also constrained arrays vs unconstrained arrays, representation of boolean values, and possibly the use of binary I/O vs text I/O. If you have labels for rows and columns, are they randomly assigned, or are the rows conceptually fixed values which can be enumerated within your program such as the example below:

type Names is (Name_1, Name_2, Name_3, Name_4, Name_5, Name_6);
type matrix is array(Names range <>, Names range <>) of Boolean;

The proper text values for True and False are True and False, not 1 and 0.
Consider the possibility of reading and writing stream files, which will greatly simplify the I/O of instances of the matrix type, which may be of different sizes.

Comment: The names of row and columns are fixed for each matrix (there will be at least 5 matrices). The goal is to read the first line parse the names out and store them for later use. Next go to the next line parse the data (row name can be bypassed) and store the parsed data (0's and 1's) in a 2d array. It is ok that the data is string data conversions can be made if necessary after storage. Run the data through the algorithm and output in a similar format to the input.

Comment: I will look into "stream files".

Comment: Please edit the question itself to make it more clear what you are actually asking.